# Find the number of words in a string starting with "a"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby, I want display the count of words starting with "a" from this string: `an ant hello hint how are you`

Answer (score 7):

You can use regex with a scan

```
string.scan(/\ba/).size
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"a asa  a ss sa a a a ass a ".split.select {|w| w[0] == "a"}.size
```

Comment: answer from rainkinz would be faster

Answer (score 0):

```
p "an ant hello hint how are you".split.count{|word| word.start_with?('a')}
#=> 3
```